# Request email audit export fails with status 400 and "Premature end of file."

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-python-client

according to https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/#creating_a_mailbox_for_export I am trying to request the email audit export of an user in G Suite this way:

```
def requestAuditExport(account):
    credentials = getCredentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    url = 'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/compliance/audit/mail/export/helpling.com/'+account
    status, response = http.request(url, 'POST', headers={'Content-Type': 'application/atom+xml'})
    print(status)
    print(response)
```

And I get the following result:

> {'content-length': '22', 'expires': 'Tue, 13 Dec 2016 14:19:37 GMT', 'date': 'Tue, 13 Dec 2016 14:19:37 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'server': 'GSE', 'status': '400', 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0', 'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,34"'}
>
> b'Premature end of file.'

I cannot see where the problem is, can someone please give me a hint?

Thanks in advance!

Kay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found out what was wrong and fixed it myself. Finally it looks like this:

```
http = getCredentials().authorize(httplib2.Http())
url = 'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/compliance/audit/mail/export/helpling.com/'+account
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/atom+xml'}
xml_data = """<atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:apps='http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006'> \
                <apps:property name='includeDeleted' value='true'/> \
              </atom:entry>"""
status, response = http.request(url, 'POST', headers=headers, body=xml_data)
```

Not sure if it was about the body or the header. It works now and I hope it will help others.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Fix it by going intp the `Admin Console`, `Manage API` client access page under `Security` and add the Client ID, scope needed for the `Directory API`. For more information, check this [document](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account).

Comment: Thanks, but this was already done. Added more scopes, no change.